# Django templates "ifless", "ifgreater"

Tags: django, django-templates

is there anything built-in in Django templates that will allow me to compare two values? Similar to ifequal.

If not - what is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built-in way of doing this, but there is a popular template tag to get it done: [smart if](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/).

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, Django 1.3 has these out of the box:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#id2